# Android app on Google Play Store is not compatible with LG G3 (Density 538, Size 2560x1440)?

Tags: android, publishing, screen-size, google-play

Android App is not compatible with LG G3 device which has high resolution and density. I have already test following config in manifest, neither support-screens nor compatible-screens nor both does not work.

```
<supports-screens
        android:anyDensity="true"
        android:largeScreens="true"
        android:normalScreens="true"
        android:smallScreens="true"
        android:xlargeScreens="true" />


<compatible-screens>

    <!-- all small size screens -->
    <screen
        android:screenDensity="ldpi"
        android:screenSize="small" />
    <screen
        android:screenDensity="mdpi"
        android:screenSize="small" />
    <screen
        android:screenDensity="hdpi"
        android:screenSize="small" />
    <screen
        android:screenDensity="xhdpi"
        android:screenSize="small" />
    <screen
        android:screenDensity="480"
        android:screenSize="small" />

    <!-- all normal size screens -->
    <screen
        android:screenDensity="ldpi"
        android:screenSize="normal" />
    <screen
        android:screenDensity="mdpi"
        android:screenSize="normal" />
    <screen
        android:screenDensity="hdpi"
        android:screenSize="normal" />
    <screen
        android:screenDensity="xhdpi"
        android:screenSize="normal" />
    <!-- Nexus 5 : 445ppi -->

    <screen
        android:screenDensity="480"
        android:screenSize="normal" />
    <!-- all large size screens -->

    <screen
        android:screenDensity="ldpi"
        android:screenSize="large" />
    <screen
        android:screenDensity="mdpi"
        android:screenSize="large" />
    <screen
        android:screenDensity="hdpi"
        android:screenSize="large" />
    <screen
        android:screenDensity="xhdpi"
        android:screenSize="large" />
    <screen
        android:screenDensity="480"
        android:screenSize="large" />
    <!-- all x large size screens -->

    <screen
        android:screenDensity="ldpi"
        android:screenSize="xlarge" />
    <screen
        android:screenDensity="mdpi"
        android:screenSize="xlarge" />
    <screen
        android:screenDensity="hdpi"
        android:screenSize="xlarge" />
    <screen
        android:screenDensity="xhdpi"
        android:screenSize="xlarge" />
    <screen
        android:screenDensity="480"
        android:screenSize="xlarge" />
</compatible-screens>
```

any suggestion?

Comment: This is not an answer, but do not use compatible-screens element.

Comment: Even without compatible-screens, it is not compatible with high density device like Galaxy S4, S65, HTC One and more, So I use compatible-screen tag to at least support them.

Comment: It seems odd, what are the required uses-feature of your app ?

Comment: The only use-feature is Blouthooth_le.

Comment: Used uses-sdk tag also specify as following: <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="18"
        android:targetSdkVersion="19" />

Answer (score 3, accepted):

See https://www.facebook.com/LGDeveloper/posts/327884754055234 for more information, but I would expect `<screen android:screenSize="normal" android:screenDensity="640" />` will work.

Comment: Thanks you for your answer, I think it should work. Currently I remove all screen related tag in manifest to support it.

Comment: @Raanan I'm having the same problem, do you know if using the above answer with screenDensity="640" and screenSize="normal" will work?  I want to limit my app to handsets only, but need to allow for the LG G3.

Comment: We added all screen sizes at screenDensity="640", but I did some digging and it looks like screenSize="normal" is the correct value for the LG G3.

Comment: I have added <screen android:screenSize="normal" android:screenDensity="640" /> to <compatible-screens> and a LG G3 user email me saying he can't download the app. :(