# Support LG G3, limit to handsets only

Tags: android, eclipse, lg

I have an Android app which is only to be available on handsets.  Currently I've used the example from the Google Docs where I set the compatible-screens elements in the manifest.  Recently a user has complained that the play store says the app is not compatible with their phone and they have a LG G3.  After looking into it, I realized the problem is most likely caused my the screen resolution of the phone not being compatible with the screens I've defined.  I came across this post [Android app on Google Play Store is not compatible with LG G3 (Density 538, Size 2560x1440)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25178959/android-app-on-google-play-store-is-not-compatible-with-lg-g3-density-538-size) which shows an additional screen element that must be defined.  My question is, can anyone confirm that using this additional screen element with the screenSize set to normal and the screenDensity set to 640 will work?

```
<screen android:screenDensity="640" android:screenSize="normal" />
```

I want to allow users with this phone to use the app, however I want to keep the app limited to only handsets at this time.

Thank you!!!

```
<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="10"
    android:targetSdkVersion="10" />

<!-- Only permit app to be used on handsets, prevent tablets -->
<compatible-screens>
    <!-- all small size screens -->
    <screen android:screenDensity="ldpi" android:screenSize="small" />
    <screen android:screenDensity="mdpi" android:screenSize="small" />
    <screen android:screenDensity="hdpi" android:screenSize="small" />
    <screen android:screenDensity="xhdpi" android:screenSize="small" />
    <screen android:screenDensity="480" android:screenSize="small" />
    <!-- all normal size screens -->
    <screen android:screenDensity="ldpi" android:screenSize="normal" />
    <screen android:screenDensity="mdpi" android:screenSize="normal" />
    <screen android:screenDensity="hdpi" android:screenSize="normal" />
    <screen android:screenDensity="xhdpi" android:screenSize="normal" />
    <!-- Nexus 5 : 445ppi -->
    <screen android:screenDensity="480" android:screenSize="normal" />
    <!-- LG G3 QHD Resolution -->
    <screen android:screenDensity="640" android:screenSize="small" />
    <screen android:screenDensity="640" android:screenSize="normal" />
</compatible-screens>
```

Comment: @tyczj excerpt from Manifest added.

Comment: what happens if you use in the `<supports_screens>` tag `android:largestWidthLimitDp="599"` since a 7inch tablet's width is 600dp. then it would seem you dont need all the compatible screens. but the real question I guess would be what do you consider a tablet since there are 6" phones that could be considered a small tablet

Comment: @tyczj Not sure, I'll have to test that and get back to you.

Comment: Are you not just trying to add xxhdpi and xxxhdpi to your supported list?

Comment: @Simon yes, that's exactly what I'm trying to do.  I just want to allow the xxhdi and xxxhdi handsets, but prevent the tablets.  Does my compatible screens elements above look to accomplish that?

Comment: @aqm Yes I believe it worked.  I have not had any complaints from users with the G3, so I assume all is working correctly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as I remember, I could allow in my PlayStore publishing account my app for each device separately. This would be more accurate but not easy to maintain.

Another approach: Try to find a feature that share the devices you intent to target. Set a `<uses feature>-Tag` accordingly. I'd think of the feature "telephony" right away. All features and usage: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/uses-feature-element.html

General information about all filters: http://developer.android.com/google/play/filters.html

Comment: But this will make app to list in some tablets which support calling.